# Turned off the dynamic mapping in Elasticsearch, but the custom mapping still not work?

Tags: dynamic, indexing, mapping, elasticsearch

my problem is: I have a JsonObject like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "type": "message",
    "body": {
    "_id": "5215bdd32de81e0c0f000005",
        "id": "411c79eb-a725-4ad9-9d82-2db54dfc80ee",
        "type": "metaModel",
        "title": "testchang",
        "authorId": "5215bd552de81e0c0f000001",
        "drawElems": [
        {
            "type": "App.draw.metaElem.ModelStartPhase",
            "id": "27re7e35-550j",
            "x": 60,
            "y": 50,
            "width": 50,
            "height": 50,
            "title": "problem engagement",
            "isGhost": true,
            "pointTo": "e88e2845-37a4-4c45-a030-d02a3c3e03f9",
            "bindingId": "90f79d70-0afc-11e3-98d2-83967d2ad9a6",
            "model": "meta",
            "entityType": "phase",
            "domainId": "411c79eb-a725-4ad9-9d82-2db54dfc80ee",
            "authorId": "5215bd552de81e0c0f000001",
            "userData": {},
            "_id": "5215f4c5d89f629c1700000d"
        },
       {...}
      ]
    }
}
```

And I tried to define a mapping as follows to index only parts of this object.

```
String mapping = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .startObject("domaindata").field("dynamic","false")
                    .startObject("properties")
                            .startObject("id").field("type","string").field("store","yes").endObject()
                           .startObject("type").field("type","string").field("store","yes").endObject()
                            .startObject("title").field("type","integer").field("store","yes").endObject()
.startObject("drawElems")
.startObject("properties")
                             .startObject("type").field("store","yes").field("type","string").endObject()
                                 .startObject("title").field("store","yes").field("type","string").endObject()
.endObject().endObject().endObject().endObject().endObject().string();
```

after adding this mapping into my type with:

```
node.client().admin()
                .indices().prepareCreate("test")
                .addMapping("domaindata", mapping)
                .execute().actionGet();
```

I still got all of the jsonobject in my indexresponse, it seems that my mapping does not work.

Could anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you get back the mapping you submitted after you created the index? Using the [get mapping api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-get-mapping/)?

Comment: @javanna I used java to get the mapping back. it looks the same with the mapping defined at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that using static mapping only means that fields that are not already present in the mapping won't be added to it, thus won't be indexed either. But as they are part of the source document that you sent, they are returned as part of the `_source` field.

Same goes if you disable a specific object in the mapping (`"enable":false`) as mentioned [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/object-type/). That object won't be parsed nor indexed, but will still be part of the stored `_source` field.

If you want to avoid storing part of the `_source` you can use the source includes/excludes feature as described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field/).